# Swift - extra argument 'count' in call?

Tags: swift

All I'm trying to do is to inverse key/values in a dictionary, and I get the following error:

extra argument 'count' in cal

```
var dictionary = SWIFT_DICTIONARY

var inverseDictionary = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjects(dictionary?.keys, forKeys: dictionary?.values, count: dictionary?.count)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var inverseDictionary = NSDictionary(objects: dictionary.keys.array, forKeys: dictionary.values.array)
```

I notice that you are unwrapping `dictionary` in your code, but it is declared as non optional. Code mistake or just copy & paste mistake?

**Addendum** - if you try the static version without the `count` parameter:

```
var inverseDictionary = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjects(dictionary.keys.array, forKeys: dictionary.values.array)
```

the compiler complains with this message:

```
'dictionaryWithObjects(_:forKeys:) is unavailable: use object construction 'NSDictionary(objects:forKeys:)'
```

I think the same happens for the other method you want to use, but the compiler doesn't report the proper error message.

Comment: Yes mistake in question, the code is correct. Your answer worked, but I'm still curious on why mine doesn't.  dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not getting that error. I'm getting a different error. Might be an Xcode beta bug. I get so many compile errors that have nothing todo with the actual errors

Comment: There are so many bugs in Xcode... but fortunately every beta release is much more stable, or better to say much less unstable :). However I have to say that in many cases it happens that what I think it's a bug, it's instead a mistake or improper use of the language